# Are the Twitter Bootstrap span classes appropriate for setting table column widths?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I inherited a project that has Bootstrap "span" classes used in tables throughout.

Is the following markup even valid? If not, why?

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="span6">Hello</td>
    <td class="span3">World</td>
    <td class="span3">2013</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I feel like it's not the right approach to setting column widths with Bootstrap.

Comment: It's only really shorthand for `width: 50%` or `width: 25%` so nothing *technically* wrong, but there are better approaches

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not *wrong*, but there is a more efficient way to set column widths in a table. Rather than setting classes on each and every `<td/>`, you could use the table's `<colgroup/>` tags. It's specifically designed for formatting table columns.

```
<table class="table">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="span6" />
    <col class="span3" />
    <col class="span3" />
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The *markup* is entirely valid. They are not actually span elements, just CSS styles. It just so happens that the CSS styles do what the developer wanted. However, these may change future versions and cause unexpected effects - so it's not recommended to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 2.x, you can set the spans **just** in the `thead th` elements, rather than for each row.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="span6">Words</th>
      <th class="span3">More Words</th>
      <th class="span3">Year</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
      <td>2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
      <td>2014</td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For Bootstrap 3.x, replace `spanX` with `col-sm-X`